# Using SASL from CentOS 7 Host to Authenticate to Active Directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, sasl, saslauthd

Trying to configure SASL on a CentOS 7 box to talk to an Active Directory installation. I've tried a couple different configurations that generate different errors. The latest:

```
No worthy mechs found
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind() failed -6 (Unknown authentication method).
Authentication failed for <user>: Retry condition (ldap server connection reset or broken) (-3)
do_auth         : auth failure: [user=<user>] [service=imap] [realm=] [mech=ldap] [reason=Unknown]
```

The contents of my `saslauthd.conf`:

```
ldap_servers: ldap://thinger.foo.bar.com:3299/
ldap_search_base: DC=foo,DC=bar,DC=com
ldap_filter: (&(cn=%u)(objectClass=user))
ldap_use_sasl: yes
ldap_auth_method: fastbind
ldap_mech: DIGEST-MD5
```

Starting to run low on ideas.

Comment: Why port 3299? That's not the usual port...

Comment: Yea, it's a bogus port. I try not to disclosing IPs, ports, names, etc. unless it's relevant to the question.

Comment: You should be careful with that. In this case it was a bad idea; it only led to needless confusion. The default LDAP port is hardly private information, for instance.

Comment: Appreciate your perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I vaguely remember that *DIGEST-MD5* requires a specific option to be enabled for the user in the MMC.

Honestly I see no value using SASL / DIGEST-MD5 today. Because to reach a sufficient security level you have to use TLS to also protect the DIGEST-MD5 authentication flow anyway.

Comment: Gotcha. I... installed the cyrus-sasl-ldap package. I changed the mech (in /etc/saslauthd.conf) to ldap. When I run testauthsasld, it gives me a new message about `ldapdb_canonuser_plug_init() failed in sasl_canonuser_add_plugin(): invalid parameter supplied` This was helpful. I've got a little more digging to do. Ty!